# I am taking CCD images through my telescope and am wondering what can I do analytically with those images?

Tags: python, ccd

This weekend I'll be taking around 50 CCD images with my Celestron CPC 8in. telescope and would like to use python to analyzie the images. Does anyone have any experience doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the python wrapper for OpenCV:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html
This should provide all the power you need to do any image processing tasks you require.
And there are some great tutorials to help you get started.

Comment: great thank you! I know this was a vague question for stackoverflow so thank you for not giving me attitude about the vagueness!